# Oracle ApexHow to store image in database table

Tags: blob, oracle-apex

In apex, i need to save the images of teammates in a table which would later be used in application for html mail formats.
I have table employee with columns empployee_name and employee_photo.
What is the ebst way to push data in the employee_photo column which is blob?

Can i use static files for the same by uploading the images there? And if yes how can i then reference them to my column?

I searched google but most methods/explanations were way too complex for a newcomer like me.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a fun thing that really should be made a bit simpler.

From memory the method I use is something like this:

Set the page item into static application files(one of the presets), then after that run some PLSQL code that takes the blob from static application files where id = :P1_ITEM, then push that into the actual table where you want it.

In case you dont already have it set up like this you will probably want to have the table of employees be a report with form, so that you can click on an employee and get a nice big form where you can enter the data, and also set up the page item with which you will add the picture.

I hope you can find your way with this, if you try and my instructions arent good enough let me know and I will get back to you when I can get to my APEX server.

EDIT: More detailed instructions:

In order to upload one persons image you will probably need a report with form page(or rather pages), these can easily be created using the wizard so I wont go into explaining them.

Then on the form page you will need a page item of the type "File Browse", lets call it P1_FILE_BROWSE for this example. We will set this item to be of storage type "Table APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES". Now this means that when you upload something into this item and submit the page, it will store in this table under the ID that is stored in P1_FILE_BROWSE.

So now we will make a process for after submit thats gonna look something like this:

```
DECLARE
  a_filename VARCHAR2(400);
  a_mime_type VARCHAR2(255);
  a_blob_content BLOB;
BEGIN
  select FILENAME, MIME_TYPE, BLOB_CONTENT  
    into a_filename, a_mime_type, a_blob_content
    from apex_application_temp_files  
   where name = :P1_FILE_BROWSE;
  
  UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET filename = a_filename,
        mime_type = a_mime_type, 
        blob_content = a_blob_content
  WHERE id_user = :P1_ID_USER
END;
```

If we go through this from the start, first we declare the three variables of the image, its name, its mime type(this process is the same for word documents or videos or whatever, the mime type tells us what this file is), and its blob content, which is the actual image.

Then we fill these variables from the APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES where the image was first stored, and then we put these variables into our table of employees.

As with all things APEX, so much more is possible, and there are multiple ways to do this, this just happens to be the one I am used to. So play around with this to make it work, good luck.

Comment: Sorry i dont follow when you say: Set the page item into static application files. How do i do this? I am very new to apex and not much good in pl/sql also. So i need more help

Comment: @PPPP I see, well I would suggest you try your best. And I will write something up in about 4 hours with some more thorough instructions for exactly how to do this.

Comment: @PPPP hey I remembered I forgot to ping you somehow with the update. But yeah, I wrote up some more stuff yesterday as promised

Comment: You mentioned, in order to put one person's image: So basically one by one, multiple images can be uploaded? If i need to upload for multiple employees?

Comment: Yeah, report with form means you get a list of employees, then when you click on one you get a new page where you can edit the details for the selected employee. So when you upload the image there, if you have it set up correctly, it will go in the table to the employee you were editing. Now you go back to the list and select another employee and edit them and repeat.